# How did Google Translate Website can modify webpage without subject to cross-site scripting?

Tags: xss, cross-site

I thought if I get a content from other site (like in iframe) then I could not do anything with it when it is not from the same domain. But Google seemed to be able to modify the text of webpage?

How can I write a JavaScript so that I can select an object in a fetched iframe then modify it client side too?

Comment: Google? Do you mean *Chrome's* auto-translation feature, or something else?

Comment: Google Translate website can translate website. Like this : https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nhk.or.jp&sandbox=1 So what I am building is a website that can annotate other website like what Google did. But I could not access the DOM elements fetched to an iframe because of cross-site policy. This policy is for security, and cannot be skipped easily for arbitrary website no? But Google seemed to did it...

Comment: Ah, I see. Translate is not *modifying* the page, it is *rewriting* it. In other words, it loads the page server-side and generates a new page that it serves you. If you examine the URL of the inner frame, you will see it is `https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?...`, not the original one.

Comment: That's a nice find. At first I thought it is because of sandbox property of that iframe. Loading other people's page and modifying it sounds like it could be subjecting to some law though? (like for doing man in the middle) Also what is the point of this cross-site policy when you can get one server and then bypass it by treating the page as your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frédéric Hamidi said in the comment, that is an answer. For the sake of completing this question I will self-answer with that.

Translate is not modifying the page, it is rewriting it. In other words, it loads the page server-side and generates a new page that it serves you. If you examine the URL of the inner frame, you will see it is `https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?...` not the original one.